# Increasing energy density for flow batteries with water based electrolyte?

Tags: battery, chemistry, energy-storage

Given a flow battery with a water based electrolyte, would it be possible to increase the energy density of battery by precipitating the redox active species from the anolyte and catholyte solutions? I am assuming the main limiting factor in energy density of flow batteries is limits on how much of the redox active species can be dissolved in water.

To give an example, say both the catholyte and anolyte tanks have two chambers: the active chamber and the precipitation chamber. The active chamber is where the normal solution would exist. Above a certain concentration, the solution would be pumped to the precipitation chamber where the water and active species would be separated and the pure water would be pumped back to the active chamber decreasing its active species concentration. A naive way to separate the water and active species might be to evaporate the water and condense it back in the active chamber. Chemistry is not my strong suit, so I could be totally off base.

Comment: This question possibly better suited for https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem is with the power consumption of such a scheme. That works against the energy density.

Comment: If significant energy density gains could be achieved, I could imagine scenarios where the tradeoff would be worth it.